# Should UIs handle 4Byte function selector collisions?

Tags: abi, design-patterns, function-selector, function-signature

With 4 bytes collisions are possible.

But they are not very likely. Currently in the 6,846 entries in the 4Byte.directory there are no collisions.

Still they are possible. Now I wonder if UIs should care for this case. Asking mainly to decide on a data-structure.

Comment: The terminology described in https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135205/what-is-a-function-signature-vs-selector-in-solidity-and-evm-languages wasn't prevalent when this question was asked, so some of the answers below may conflate the terminology. (Anyone can suggest edits to them.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different issues that we need to separate:

**User confusion due to accidental hash collision** is indeed something that we worry about, although it should be rare and improbable. If the user tries to do an action whose selector is the same as some other, then it means that the app will either not be able to decode their data on the confirmation window, or if it can, show the wrong function. It's rare and easily avoidable by the app developer if they want. The interface can deal with this by trying multiple hash collisions to see which one is able to decode the whole message, or by simply setting them by the contract byte code.

**Possible phishing attempt due to hash collision** is something that seems very implausible to me. It's important to note that the function name is set by the contract code, which can do whatever it wants regardless of the function name. During a transaction confirmation, it doesn't really matter if the function *name* is `donateToSavePuppies` or `killAllPuppies`, what matters is what the contract itself does, and that's what the interface should worry about. So anyone building interfaces for ethereum should have all sorts of tools to defend users from scams: whitelists, blacklists, flags if the code is not open, stamps claiming the code has been audited etc, and more importantly *making sure that the contract you are interacting with is the one you believe to be*. If a scammer wants to fool users with an evil contract, they don't need to worry about finding collisions, they can just use the name they want.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I accepted this answer as it is the most relevant to my question. Was mainly wondering about implications of collisions which this answer focuses on - not the probability of them which most other answer focused on (still thanks a lot for the input there too)

Answer (score 6):

I'll start with the disclaimer that I know next to nothing about Ethereum, and that the first I heard of 4-byte signatures was when I clicked this question in the Hot Network Questions sidebar.

That said, according to https://www.4byte.directory/:

> These 4-byte signatures are defined as the first four bytes of the Keccak hash (SHA3) of the canonical representation of the function signature. [...] There are [currently] 6,846 signatures in the database[.]

This means that, ignoring any brute-force attempts to deliberately pick a particular signature (like the example [given by Martin Swende](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/40302)), each signature is basically a (pseudo)random 32-bit string.  Since there are a total of 2<sup>32</sup> distinct such strings, the probability of at least one random collision occurring between two signatures will rise sharply as the number of signatures approaches the [birthday bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) of about 2<sup>16</sup> = 65,536 signatures.

That's about 10 times the current number of signatures.  I have no idea how rapidly that number may be growing, but if it *is* growing at all, the fact that it's already about 1/10 of the way to the birthday bound suggests that it likely will sooner or later reach it.  And once it does, the number of collisions will [grow rapidly.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Collision_counting)  So if you want your code to keep working even after that happens, you really should plan on having a way to handle collisions.

Comment: That day has come https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0x01ffc9a7
There are now 663,517 hashed signature in the 4byte database, way past the birthday bound you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

So, it's not that hard to create a collision. For the fun of it, I tried a while back to find something which has the selector `0x00000000`. Here it is: `overdiffusingness(bytes,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256)`. However, the chances of a conflict which

- Has the same selector
- Has the same length for data
- Has ABI-encoding which 'fit' both

... Are quite slim. In the overdiffusingness example, any valid call needs to send at minimum `4x32` (for the uints) and `32+N` for the `bytes`. If it was to conflict with e.g `foobar(address)` on the raw 4byte-level , the conflict can easily be resolved if the UI has access to calldata.

I'm not sure I understand the question, but sure, a database of 4byte-selectors *should* allow for several entries on the same selector.

Comment: Thanks - for the data structure I should not factor in these filters: "Has the same length for data" and "Has ABI-encoding which 'fit' both" - mainly need to know if 1:n n:m - tending to n:m now

Answer (score 3):

Imho yes, they should. Accidental collisions are probably unlikely, but we wouldn't want UIs to go belly up.

Malicious collisions however would be a whole different story, and it would be nice to detect these. A future direction might be to pick the correct "collision" based on the contract's bytecode. But that's a whole new can of worms.

Bu this is my 2c.

Comment: Thanks for these 2c - much appreciated! You mean detection by analyzing the parameters?

Comment: I don't have any specific ideas on that front, just played around with the thought of whether we could figure out which 4byte interpretation is the correct one based on contextual infos :)