# How to calculate the 4byte selector using Cast?

Tags: abi, foundry, function-selector, function-signature, cast

I am using [Foundry](https://getfoundry.sh/), and I need to calculate the [4-byte selector](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135205/what-is-a-function-signature-and-function-selector-in-solidity-and-evm-language) of a custom error. How can I do this with the `cast` CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cast sig` for this, which takes a single input in the form of `NAME(type1,type2,...)`.

Here's an example:

```sh
$ cast sig "transfer(address,uint256)"
```

Will output:

```
0xa9059cbb
```